# Azure SQL: Archive a sql database before deleting

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have a number of sql databases in azure sql which I believe are no longer in use.

I'm planning on deleting them however, as a precaution, I would like to take some kind of backup or archive copies that I can quickly use to restore each database if necessary.

I've googled around but haven't found anything concrete.  I found one mention of making a copy in a storage account so that it can be recovered but haven't been able to find how to do it - the copy command makes a copy of the database to another database.  The "restore" option disappears after you remove a database.

The Database's in question are all less than 10mb in size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider using an export of the database as a bacpac to a cheap Blob Storage account.

[image]

On the Storage field on below image you can provide an existent Storage Account or create a new one.

[image]

If you need to recover one of those databases you just need to import them and specify the location of the bacpac you want to import.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your, that's exactly what I was looking for!  Also now that I know the files are called 'bacpac' google yields more results.

Comment: I am gald this works based on your needs. I export Production databases on sunday to Azure Storage and retain them for a year using PowerShell, in case you may find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can export your Azure SQL database to the [BACPAC backup files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/data-tier-applications?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15#bacpac),  store these backup file to Azure Blob Storage or your on-premise computer.

You can restore the your Azure SQL database from the bacpac files when you need.

Alberto Morllo provides the way about [export the database to Blob Storage On Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export#export-to-a-bacpac-file-using-the-azure-portal).

Beside this, there are  many ways can help you do that, please reference:

1. [Export to a BACPAC file using the SQLPackage utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export#export-to-a-bacpac-file-using-the-sqlpackage-utility);
2. [Export to a BACPAC file using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export#export-to-a-bacpac-file-using-sql-server-management-studio-ssms)
3. [Export to a BACPAC file using PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export#export-to-a-bacpac-file-using-powershell)

Get more details, please reference:

1. [Quickstart: Import a BACPAC file to a database in Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-import?tabs=azure-powershell)
2. [Export an Azure SQL database to a BACPAC file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export):

You can choose the way you like best.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for further information it will bring all the docs together for anyone else googling it.  The powershell option sounds quite handy for automating a regular backup